# Unable to deploy shiny app with shinyapps.io

Tags: shiny

Help please - what is the cause of this error?

Note: my application works well locally.

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE  
Uploading bundle for application: 2363487...Detecting system locale ... DONE  
Deploying bundle: 3194815 for application: 2363487 ...  
Waiting for task: 737583366  
  building: Parsing manifest  
  building: Building image: 3571613  
  building: Installing system dependencies
  building: Fetching packages
  building: Installing packages
  building: Installing files
  building: Pushing image: 3571613
deploying: Starting instances
rollforward: Activating new instances
unstaging: Stopping old instances

Application successfully deployed to https://khol-ben.shinyapps.io/mindshare/
```

> Warning message:
>   Error detecting locale: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'raw'
>   (Using default: en_US)

Comment: its seems to be a text file problem, make sure you have an empty space a final line in the text file

Comment: I am using only xlsx as input file. and if it is so i think it wont to work locally as well. but in my case it works locally. and when the app opens after the deployment only the first page of login appears and when i click on login it says that unable to connect to the server

Comment: [This](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/260) might be related.